# How to identify client PHP Socket?

Tags: php, sockets

So I've got myself a regular PHP socket (More or less the same code from the example from the php manual). I have found a way to detect when a client disconnects (gracefully or not), but how can I identify who it was? IP address use is out because there might be more than one user with the same IP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define "who it was" in this case? What information exactly are you trying to identify about the socket?

Comment: Implement some sort of authentication service. At the most basic form, have the user send a username and password, and assign him a connection ID.

Comment: Well this socket is for a flash based chat. I need to identify who disconnects. Hope that makes sense. And due to it being a disconnect event, I obviously cant have the client/server interact because they are well.. disconnected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think about what is delivered in a [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) or UDP packet header, there isn't much identity information included, just the IP address. If you want to know the identity of clients you need to have them send some sort of unique identifier (e.g. username & password as @madara commented). If they're from the same IP that means that they're using the same router in which case its purpose is to mask what devices are behind the router.

To detect who disconnected, you first need to determine who connected. Each connection gets its own socket, even if they're coming from the same IP address. In psuedo php:

```
// Store all active sockets in an array
$online_users = array();

// Open up a listening socket
$listener = socket_create(...);
socket_listen($listener);
$client_sock = socket_accept($listener);

// Have the client send authentication stuff after connecting and
// we'll receive it on the server side
$username = socket_read($client_sock, $len);
// Map the username to the client socket
$online_users[$username] = $client_sock;

// Continue to read or write data to/from the sockets. When a read or
// write fails, you just iterate through the array to find out who
// it was. If the socket $failed_sock failed, do as follows
foreach ($online_users as $name => $socket)
{
    if ($socket == $failed_sock)
    {
        // $name is the username of the client that disconnected
        echo $name . ' disconnected';
        // You can then broadcast to your other clients that $name
        // disconnected. You can also do your SQL query to update the
        // db here.
        // Finally remove the entry for the disconnected client
        unset($online_users[$name]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I guess I didnt make this clear in my original question. I need to get the id of the client that disconnected. I need to have the server assign an id to each connection or something. Again, I cant have the client/server interact after disconnect.

Comment: If you implement an authentication system, you'll know who connects to your socket, then since you keep an instance of the socket (for replying etc), when the client disconnects, the socket will close or timeout and you'll know who it was. Just keep some sort of hash with username -> socket.

Comment: Sorry, Im not understanding. There is an authentication system in place. And its working well (MySQL database). Im confused on your suggestion though. Perhaps a bit of code or something? I would know how to log a user out on disconnect, yes of course simple SQL query. But how would I know which user to remove/logout?

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to give it a go :)

Comment: I just wanted to that within  $clinet_sock there's a 'Resource ID #X' is given
is that reliable or not ?

Answer (score 2):

Logically in your case this is tough one! Here's just an idea:

If it's for a chat how about storing all online users in a database or flat file with the following columns:

```
NICKNAME
IP
TIME
```

And create a function that will check these and update accordingly the time let's say every 10 seconds. Based on that you'll be able to determine when and who's is online/offline.

------ UPDATE ------

Check your socket error?
Use get_last_error() to check the error code.

```
$errorcode = socket_last_error(); 
$errormsg=socket_strerror($errorcode); 
die("Error: (".$errorcode.") ".$errormsg."\n");
```

Unset the user:

```
if($data === FALSE) {
    socket_close($clients[$i]['socket']);
    unset($clients[$i]);
    echo 'Client disconnected!',"\r\n";
    continue;
}
```

Unset the client from the database. You can also identify the exact nickname from the $clients array by their ID.

Comment: I do actually have a database like that, its how the online users are loaded when you login. :) The problem is... when someone disconnects, if I cant tell who disconnected, how will I know which user to remove from the database? :(

Comment: Thats pretty much what I have now, but what from that would I send to MySQL to remove the offline user?

Comment: What do you have in you $clients array? Any id associated with the nickname? Or nickname?
Just use print_r($clients); and paste the output here.