# How to send message to single client

Tags: php, sockets

I am starting work with PHP Socket.

I have a problem. I need to identify clients that connect through a token and after identification send reserved messages only to these clients.

How can I do this?

Remember: the [How to identify client PHP Socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609134/how-to-identify-client-php-socket/12609321) solution is not possible, I already tried. Because I use a proxy via Apache to publish this socket, and identification by IP is not possible.
It must be the token key that must be informed by the client, as it is random at each access.

```
<?php
define('HOST_NAME',"localhost"); 
define('PORT',"8090");
$null = NULL;

class ChatHandler {
    function send($message) {
        global $clientSocketArray;
        $messageLength = strlen($message);
        foreach($clientSocketArray as $clientSocket)
        {
            @socket_write($clientSocket,$message,$messageLength);
        }
        return true;
    }

    function unseal($socketData) {
        $length = ord($socketData[1]) & 127;
        if($length == 126) {
            $masks = substr($socketData, 4, 4);
            $data = substr($socketData, 8);
        }
        elseif($length == 127) {
            $masks = substr($socketData, 10, 4);
            $data = substr($socketData, 14);
        }
        else {
            $masks = substr($socketData, 2, 4);
            $data = substr($socketData, 6);
        }
        $socketData = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
            $socketData .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
        }
        return $socketData;
    }

    function seal($socketData) {
        $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
        $length = strlen($socketData);

        if($length <= 125)
            $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
        elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
            $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
        elseif($length >= 65536)
            $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
        return $header.$socketData;
    }

    function doHandshake($received_header,$client_socket_resource, $host_name, $port) {
        $headers = array();
        $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $received_header);
        foreach($lines as $line)
        {
            $line = chop($line);
            if(preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches))
            {
                $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
            }
        }

        $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'] ?? null;
        $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
        $buffer  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
        "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
        "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
        "WebSocket-Origin: $host_name\r\n" .
        "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host_name:$port/api/socket\r\n".
        "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
        socket_write($client_socket_resource,$buffer,strlen($buffer));
    }

    function newConnectionACK($client_ip_address) {
        $message = 'Novo cliente ' . $client_ip_address.' entrou';
        $messageArray = array('message'=>$message,'message_type'=>'chat-connection-ack');
        $ACK = $this->seal(json_encode($messageArray));
        return $ACK;
    }

    function connectionDisconnectACK($client_ip_address) {
        $message = 'Cliente ' . $client_ip_address.' desconectado';
        $messageArray = array('message'=>$message,'message_type'=>'chat-connection-ack');
        $ACK = $this->seal(json_encode($messageArray));
        return $ACK;
    }

    function createChatBoxMessage($chat_user,$chat_box_message) {
        $message = $chat_user . ": <div class='chat-box-message'>" . $chat_box_message . "</div>";
        $messageArray = array('message'=>$message,'message_type'=>'chat-box-html');
        $chatMessage = $this->seal(json_encode($messageArray));
        return $chatMessage;
    }
}
$chatHandler = new ChatHandler();

$socketResource = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($socketResource, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($socketResource, 0, PORT);
socket_listen($socketResource);

$clientSocketArray = array($socketResource);
while (true) {
    $newSocketArray = $clientSocketArray;
    socket_select($newSocketArray, $null, $null, 0, 10);

    if (in_array($socketResource, $newSocketArray)) {
        $newSocket = socket_accept($socketResource);
        $clientSocketArray[] = $newSocket;

        $header = socket_read($newSocket, 1024);
        $chatHandler->doHandshake($header, $newSocket, HOST_NAME, PORT);

        socket_getpeername($newSocket, $client_ip_address);
        $connectionACK = $chatHandler->newConnectionACK($client_ip_address);

        $chatHandler->send($connectionACK);

        $newSocketIndex = array_search($socketResource, $newSocketArray);
        unset($newSocketArray[$newSocketIndex]);
    }

    foreach ($newSocketArray as $newSocketArrayResource) {  
        while(socket_recv($newSocketArrayResource, $socketData, 1024, 0) >= 1){
            $socketMessage = $chatHandler->unseal($socketData);
            $messageObj = json_decode($socketMessage);

            $chat_box_message = $chatHandler->createChatBoxMessage($messageObj->chat_user ?? 'sistema', $messageObj->chat_message ?? 'nao identificado');
            $chatHandler->send($chat_box_message);
            break 2;
        }

        $socketData = @socket_read($newSocketArrayResource, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
        if ($socketData === false) { 
            socket_getpeername($newSocketArrayResource, $client_ip_address);
            $connectionACK = $chatHandler->connectionDisconnectACK($client_ip_address);
            $chatHandler->send($connectionACK);
            $newSocketIndex = array_search($newSocketArrayResource, $clientSocketArray);
            unset($clientSocketArray[$newSocketIndex]);         
        }
    }
}
socket_close($socketResource);
```

This code works perfectly.

But I want to identify the customer and send specific messages.

In this case, each client that connects must show a token, in which I will identify and show the records that belong to them.

And when sending the result, the socket should send only to him and not to all clients.

For example, I have a table in MySQL that lists the requests of all users, so when sending the response, I must send filtered only to which the user belongs and not all clients.

---

Answer (score 0):

After further research, I found a solution to the problem. And I want to post here to help others who have this need or learning.

In order for the server to send messages to websocket, this code must be used:

````
$host = 'localhost';  // your websocket server
$port = 8090;
$local = "http://localhost";  // url where this script runs | Client
$messageArray = array('chat_user'=>'EXEMPLE','chat_message'=>'MESSAGE CONTENT TO SEND FROM OTHER SCRIPT PHP');
$data = json_encode($messageArray);  // data to be sent

$head = "GET / HTTP/1.1"."\r\n".
        "Upgrade: WebSocket"."\r\n".
        "Connection: Upgrade"."\r\n".
        "Origin: $local"."\r\n".
        "Host: $host"."\r\n".
        "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13"."\r\n".
        "Sec-WebSocket-Key: ".base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1(time() . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')))."\r\n".
        "Content-Length: ".strlen($data)."\r\n"."\r\n";

// WebSocket handshake
$sock = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 2);
fwrite($sock, $head ) or die('error:'.$errno.':'.$errstr);
$headers = fread($sock, 2000);
fwrite($sock, hybi10Encode($data)) or die('error:'.$errno.':'.$errstr);
$wsdata = fread($sock, 2000);
fclose($sock);

var_dump(hybi10Decode($wsdata));

// hibi10 decoding of data
function hybi10Decode($data)
{
    $bytes = $data;
    $dataLength = '';
    $mask = '';
    $coded_data = '';
    $decodedData = '';
    $secondByte = sprintf('%08b', ord($bytes[1]));
    $masked = ($secondByte[0] == '1') ? true : false;
    $dataLength = ($masked === true) ? ord($bytes[1]) & 127 : ord($bytes[1]);
    if($masked === true)
    {
        if ($dataLength === 126) {
           $mask = substr($bytes, 4, 4);
           $coded_data = substr($bytes, 8);
        }
        elseif ($dataLength === 127) {
            $mask = substr($bytes, 10, 4);
            $coded_data = substr($bytes, 14);
        }
        else {
            $mask = substr($bytes, 2, 4);       
            $coded_data = substr($bytes, 6);        
        }   
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($coded_data); $i++) {       
            $decodedData .= $coded_data[$i] ^ $mask[$i % 4];
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($dataLength === 126) {          
           $decodedData = substr($bytes, 4);
        }
        elseif ($dataLength === 127) {           
            $decodedData = substr($bytes, 10);
        } 
        else {               
            $decodedData = substr($bytes, 2);       
        }       
    }   

    return $decodedData;
}

// hibi10 encoding of data
function hybi10Encode($payload, $type = 'text', $masked = true) {
    $frameHead = array();
    $frame = '';
    $payloadLength = strlen($payload);

    switch ($type) {
        case 'text':
            // first byte indicates FIN, Text-Frame (10000001):
            $frameHead[0] = 129;
            break;
        case 'close':
            // first byte indicates FIN, Close Frame(10001000):
            $frameHead[0] = 136;
            break;
        case 'ping':
            // first byte indicates FIN, Ping frame (10001001):
            $frameHead[0] = 137;
            break;
        case 'pong':
            // first byte indicates FIN, Pong frame (10001010):
            $frameHead[0] = 138;
            break;
     }

    // set mask and payload length (using 1, 3 or 9 bytes)
    if ($payloadLength > 65535) {
        $payloadLengthBin = str_split(sprintf('%064b', $payloadLength), 8);
        $frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? 255 : 127;
        for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
            $frameHead[$i + 2] = bindec($payloadLengthBin[$i]);
        }

        // most significant bit MUST be 0 (close connection if frame too big)
        if ($frameHead[2] > 127) {
            $this->close(1004);
            return false;
        }
    } elseif ($payloadLength > 125) {
        $payloadLengthBin = str_split(sprintf('%016b', $payloadLength), 8);
        $frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? 254 : 126;
        $frameHead[2] = bindec($payloadLengthBin[0]);
        $frameHead[3] = bindec($payloadLengthBin[1]);
    } else {
        $frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? $payloadLength + 128 : $payloadLength;
    }

    // convert frame-head to string:
    foreach (array_keys($frameHead) as $i) {
        $frameHead[$i] = chr($frameHead[$i]);
    }
    if ($masked === true) {
        // generate a random mask:
        $mask = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
            $mask[$i] = chr(rand(0, 255));
        }
        $frameHead = array_merge($frameHead, $mask);
    }
    $frame = implode('', $frameHead);
    // append payload to frame:
    for ($i = 0; $i < $payloadLength; $i++) {
        $frame .= ($masked === true) ? $payload[$i] ^ $mask[$i % 4] : $payload[$i];
    }

    return $frame;
}```
````